# CiviVolunteer Commitment box control

Tags: civivolunteer

On the search for volunteer opportunities page the commitment box with the signup button floats on the screen. I'd like to prevent this as it obscures the list of opportunities. Does anyone have a recommendation on the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve via css. I commented out lines 112 & 116 in this file: /org.civicrm.volunteer/ang/volunteer.css. The cart still floats is just stays in position as opposed to being in a fixed point while scrolling. Below is the edited css excerpt.

```
 .crm-vol-half-responsive.crm-vol-opp-cart.floating_cart {
 /* position: fixed;*/
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 200px;
 /* width: 20%; */
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite annoying isn't it? I am not sure if this was the only change I did but I edited the core file https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/blob/22eb7ca6dbf99cddb6c43405a88f2cdf83ae7609/ang/volunteer/VolOppsCtrl.js#L224

and changed from 'scroll' to 'click'. Might not be the best way but it worked.